# how to resolve error SyntaxError: Unexpected comma in array literal (line 27, file "Code")?

Tags: javascript

I try to run script at google script.
my script is like this

```
function doGet(e) {

  var sourceText = ''
  if (e.parameter.q){
    sourceText = e.parameter.q;
  }

  var sourceLang = 'auto';
  if (e.parameter.source){
    sourceLang = e.parameter.source;
  }

  var targetLang = 'ja';
  if (e.parameter.target){
    targetLang = e.parameter.target;
  }

  /* Option 1 */

  var translatedText = LanguageApp.translate(sourceText, sourceLang, targetLang)

  /* Option 2 */  

  var url = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=" 
            + sourceLang + "&tl=" + targetLang + "&dt=t&q=" + encodeURI(sourceText);

  var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());

  translatedText = result[0][0][0];

  var json = {
    'sourceText' : sourceText,
    'translatedText' : translatedText
  };

  // set JSONP callback
  var callback = 'callback';
  if(e.parameter.callback){
    callback = e.parameter.callback
  }

  // return JSONP
  return ContentService
           .createTextOutput(callback + '(' + JSON.stringify(json) + ')')
           .setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JAVASCRIPT);
}
```

when i try to run this script it give error like this:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected comma in array literal (line 27, file "Code").

How to resolve this error?

Error line is this:

```
  var result = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText());
```

Answer (score 0):

The url you entered does not return a valid json, I tried to use your url like this:

> https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=fr&tl=en&dt=t&q=salut

and it gave me that output, which is clearly not a json:

```
[[["Hello","salut",,,1]],,"fr"]
```